# Earning Line, plotting a line from input values

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to have a line on the TV charts that represents the earnings of a given company quarter after quarter. I have no problem in inputting the Earning value myself for each company, but need some help to create that line, the inputs are the quarter earnings release and the associated earnings number. The idea would be to have that Earnings Line on the chart itself and with its own scale, just like when you use the "compare -> add symbol" with the "overlay the main chart" option activated. The idea is to see the growth (or lack there of) of earnings through time and see how it guides the stock price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows quarterly earnings, estimate and dividends. It will overlay on scale *None*, so it is independent of the chart's scale.

```
//@version=4
// Unsupported security call feature. No guarantee it will work in the future.
study("Earnings", "", true, scale = scale.none)
earnings = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_EARNINGS", "3M", close[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
estimate = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_EARNINGS", "3M", open[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dividends = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_DIVIDENDS", "3M", close[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(earnings, "Earnings")
plot(estimate, "Estimate", transp = 75)
plot(dividends, "Dividends", color.orange)
```

[image]

[EDIT 2019.09.03 12:29 — LucF]
All the lines now connect. Follow comments in code if you want the staircase effect back for some. I added dots on quarters. You can remove them by unchecking the checkbox in the script's *Settings/Inputs*.

```
//@version=4
// Unsupported security call feature. No guarantee it will work in the future.
study("Earnings", "", true, scale = scale.none)
plotDots = input(true, "Plot dots")
// In order to plot in staircases instead, use "gaps = barmerge.gaps_off".
earnings    = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_EARNINGS", "3M",  close[1],   gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
estimate    = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_EARNINGS", "3M",  open[1],    gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dividends   = security("ESD:" + syminfo.prefix + "_" + syminfo.ticker + "_DIVIDENDS", "3M", close[1],   gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
// Plot lines.
plot(earnings,  "Earnings")
plot(estimate,  "Estimate", transp = 75)
plot(dividends, "Dividends", color.orange)
// Plot dots.
plot(plotDots ? earnings  : na, "Earnings", style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(plotDots ? estimate  : na, "Estimate", transp = 75, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(plotDots ? dividends : na, "Dividends", color.orange, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much, just one more thing, is there the possibility to adjust the scale of the line, just like you are able to "squeeze" or "expand" the price axis in the norma charts ?

Comment: From the indicator's dropdown menu, choose *Pin to scale/Pin to new right-left scale*. Another scale will be created, which you can then squeeze or expand independently from the price scale.

Comment: perfect , thank you ! One last thing, do you think is possible to have just a line connecting the earnings number to the next one each quarter ?  Instead of having  the flat line for the full quarter and then straight jump to the next value when is released ?