# Earnings line in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot a line per earnings in tradingview. so if I am on daily timeframe, and i got 4 earnings - 3 in the past and 1 in the future, i want a vertical line for each, and I also want the date on the line itself. eg '31st May Earnings'. it would be awesome if the text alignement could be changed to top/bottom or middle if the text is obscured by bars itself. I am studying 100's of stocks everyday and adding these manually is becoming extremely cumbersome.

I am fairly new to PineScript so no clue where to begin.

I looked at this Stack Overflow question, and tried to use some of this code, but it just errors out for me!

[Earning Line, plotting a line from input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741638/earning-line-plotting-a-line-from-input-values)